# Using IPTables to forward all packes along certain route

Tags: iptables

I have a router running DD-WRT with 4 ethernet ports. Let's call them eth0 through eth3. And wifi interfaces: wifi0 and wifi1.

What would be the optimal iptable setup to forward all traffic along these routes, both ways.

- eth0 to eth1
- eth0 to eth2
- eth2 to wifi0
- eth2 to wifi1

The current command template I'm using to forward from eth0 to eth1 is as follows:

```
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o eth1 -j ACCEPT
```

I'm not sure what series of commands I must execute to make sure I don't have any conflicts.

Comment: Your iptables rule doesn't forward the packets, just allows forwarding they from interface `eth0` to `interface eth1`.

Comment: Netfilter is a **filter** if you want to define routes, add routes.

Comment: @AntonDanilov can I modify it to actively forward?

Comment: Explain, please, what you want to achieve, because it isn't clear.

Comment: @AntonDanilov essentially any packet coming from eth0 should be automatically routed to the mentioned destinations disregarding any other routing info

Comment: In your setup there is a conceptual issue. You've written you want route packets from `eth0` to `eth2`, and from `eth2` to `wifi0` and to `wifi1`. But in this case you cannot get bidirectional connect between hosts, connected to `eth0` and `eth2`. Anyway ethernet isn't point-to-point and you cannot just route packets to interface, only to hosts with some addresses.

Comment: @AntonDanilov the implication was that it worked both ways. Clarified. While ethernt is point to point, can"t I have the router just forward the packets anyway?